# False before version of the package in package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarnpkg

I'm using Yarn to install my packages. Lately I discovered that when I install some package, for example, the latest version of React(16.8.2), in `package.json` (in dependencies section) appears *false* just before the version number, like that:

```
"react": "false16.8.2",
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your configs in .yarnrc and scan for the 'save-prefix' settings.

The correct setting should be:

```
 'save-prefix': '^'
```

[Yarn adds "false" as version range instead of default ^](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5587)